# Powershell - Importing Information on Excel, Running through AD

Tags: powershell

I've been given a spreadsheet asking for clarification if the below 600 or so users have e-mail accounts. I have their names which I can run through `Active Directory`. I'm not going through all of them so I want to create a `PowerShell` script to do it for me.

I appreciate I'm being fairly lazy as I could probably find out by myself, but I'm fairly strapped for time. Help would be very much appreciated.

So basically I want to do the following:

- Import Excel Spreadsheet ("Spreadsheet with names of users")
- Check Columns "G, F" (surname, forename) and input values into AD.

`IF` names are found, return name and e-mail.
`else` print
"no account".

Comment: So you want to update AD Users based on a Excel Sheet?

Comment: I don't want to edit anything in AD. I want to take information from it. Editing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid Excel itself unless you absolutely cannot. If I assume the content is converted to a CSV file it can be achieved something like this.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv SpreadsheetAsCsv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $givenName = $_.Forename
    $sn = $_.Surname
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { givenName -eq $givenName -and sn -eq $sn } -Properties EmailAddress

    $Entry = $_ | Select-Object Forename, Surname, Name, Email, Notes

    if (($ADUser | Measure-Object).Count -gt 1) {
        $Entry.Notes = 'Too many matches ({0})' -f ($ADUser.SamAccountName -join ', ')
    } elseif ($ADUser) {
        $Entry.Email = $ADUser.EmailAddress
        $Entry.Name = $ADUser.Name
    } else {
        $Entry.Notes = 'No account'
    }

    $Entry
} | Export-Csv NewCsvFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Ok that's great. Getting somewhere. However, what's the specific cmdlet to cycle through the rows on the CSV?

Comment: Import-Csv is doing that. ForEach-Object is consuming the content with a loop to allow access to individual rows via $_.